# Portfolio Page for Classic Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

My theme has an 4 column portfolio page layout for my portfolio posts. And when I add a portfolio item it automatically shows up in my portfolio page.
That's okay.
But I need to do this for classic posts as well.
Is there a way to do this?

I found these codes in my shortcodes.php file

Thank you for your time.

Comment: yes, it's mostly possible, but it depends on a theme or some deeper customization, tell us the name of the theme

Comment: you need the posts to show up, or you need them to show up on the portfolio page or you need them to show up in a 4 column layout?  Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Theme's name is Vittoria. If you check below site you will see what i need. What i really need is; i want my posts shows up like below site; http://www.ekinmakina.com/urunler